# Any+Time DatePicker: accept only current and past dates, not future

Tags: javascript, datetime, anytime

Might anyone know what I need to add to one of the best calendar widgets out there to disable future dates?

```
$("#div").AnyTime_picker({latest:(new Date())});
```

Comment: RTFM—it already has switches for [earliest](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#AnyTime.picker.earliest) and [latest](http://www.ama3.com/anytime/#AnyTime.picker.latest).

Comment: @RobG Does this seem right?  $("#div").AnyTime_picker({latest:(new Date())});

Comment: Dunno, I don't use it. I just went to the site an poked through the documentation, but what you have looks ok.